# Outputting wordpress custom date field in different format

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-fields

Okay, so I have a custom date field set up as 'm/d/Y H:i:s' and I'd like to echo that as 'M j'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it stored in the format m/d/Y H:i:s, then you can do this wherever the date is echoed in your template:

```
echo date('M j',strtotime($custom_date));
```